# C# Reflection- using FieldInfo.SetValue to set a struct field to null safe?

Tags: c#, reflection

If you use C# reflection to set a (non-nullable) value-type field to null, it appears to accept that and just sets the default value.  But since this behavior is slightly unexpected (I'd expect an exception) and I can't find any docs describing this behavior, I want to know if this is safe.  Or am I relying on some undocumented / undefined behavior?

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        FieldInfo pointField = (typeof(ClassWithAPoint)).GetField("point");
        
        ClassWithAPoint classWithAPoint = new ClassWithAPoint();
        classWithAPoint.point.x = 1;
        classWithAPoint.point.y = 2;

        //This works to create a default Point struct (0, 0).  But is this safe?
        pointField.SetValue(classWithAPoint, null);
        
        
        //Prints: "Point = 0, 0"
        Console.WriteLine($"Point = {classWithAPoint.point.x}, {classWithAPoint.point.y}");
    }
    
    public struct Point
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }
    
    public class ClassWithAPoint
    {
        public Point point;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it has always been this way. The docs are open source. Perhaps make a pull request on the documentation so that a note is added

Comment: If you use setValue with a property setter instead of a field then put a breakpoint inside you see that `Unmanaged` code is setting the value. There's no convert involved. So my guess would be that the mapping from unmanaged to managed code will take care of the struct not being null.

Answer (score -1):

The behaviour of `FieldInfo.SetValue()` under these circumstances is not explicitly documented/defined as far as I can find (Feb 2022) but because it takes object (reference type) parameters, any value type value must be boxed.

The behaviour of `Convert.To[U]IntXX(object)` is to return zero for a null parameter, confirmed by documentation which says something equivalent to this statement for `Int32` "A 32-bit signed integer equivalent to the value of value, or zero if value is null."

So you should be safe as long as `SetValue()` remains true to (consistent with) `Convert()` method behaviours and documentation.

*** A word of caution ***
Try setting a `char` field value to null using `FieldInfo.SetValue()`. `Convert.ToChar(null)` currently (.NET 6.0) throws a `NullReferenceException` even though the documentation says "The Unicode character equivalent to the value of value. -or- Char.MinValue if value equals null." but the behaviour itself is consistent with the (C#) fact that other types do not have implicit conversions to `char`.

Comment: Why do you feel Convert is involved?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: since null is not assignable to int a conversion has to be involved. Should the conversion here (I haven't trawled the source code) not align with Convert method behaviour, I'd call that a bug.  But it does align as the OP observed.  I'd also say the behaviour of `Convert.ToChar(object)` where the parameter is null is correct (and documentation should be fixed) because no value types can convert implicitly to char. But that is also opinion based on an assumption/expectation of internal consistency on my part.  I've softened the 3rd paragraph of my answer. Thanks

Comment: But he's not assigning anything to an int, he's assigning the whole struct. Yes, the struct happens to contain ints, but that's not relevant I believe.

Comment: You are correct.